# Changing fragment with click on imagebutton

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android. And I am trying to create an app where i have three `imagebuttons` on top in a horizontal line and fragment in below portion which can change with click of button (same like tinder android app). I have tried using two different fragments, one with three image buttons and other the below one). Then I also tried using `gridview` for images and then fragment in the below portion. I have also tried simply using images and dynamically changing fragments. I have got different errors resulting in crashes. What I want to know is how can I achieve my objective in most efficient way?

**EDIT :** Codes are following when I am using just images without `gridview` or fragments for `imagebuttons`.

```
package com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ImageButton ngosButton, profileButtton, donateButton;
    NGOsFragment ngosFragment;
    ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    DonateFragment donateFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ngosButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ngoButton);
        profileButtton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.profileButton);
        donateButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.donateButton);

        ngosButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragTrans.add(R.id.fragment_container, ngosFragment);
                fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTrans.commit();
            }
        });
    }

}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    tools:context="com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20.MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ngoButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ngo"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/donateButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:src="@drawable/donate"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Rest I have three fragments(NGOsFragment, DonateFragment and ProfileFragment), which I have not changed. I have not added onclicklistener for rest of button in here.

```
  07-25 21:18:09.111 23385-23407/com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-25 21:18:09.111 23385-23407/com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-25 21:18:18.321 23385-23385/com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20, PID: 23385
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:418)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:408)
                                                                                      at com.psycho.ayush.sahanubhooti_20.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Share the **relevant** code + the logcat of the error.

Comment: You should really use a tablayout instead. You can check this link : https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware about tablayout. I have added the log and relevant  codes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However,. Please format and edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

set on click listener on all the buttons and set the below code to set the different fragments on the frame layout. The frame layout id is the resource id of the frame layout you set in the activity and Fragment class is the fragment you created to be called on the click of the image buttons.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame layout id, Fragment class name).commit()
```

Comment: I have done this but still app crashes on clicking that button. I have added the code and log above info level

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml file code. I think the issue is with dat...

it's better to use tab layout, for such feature. Go thru the link below. It is one of the best link to learn about the tabs....
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/